# fill values of a column with values from another column (but not on the same row), conditionally, in R

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

I have a question about how to fill values of a column with values from another column (but not on the same line), conditionally.
Let me explain the situation with an example of my dataset.
This is my dataset, where two individuals (ID) column are engaged in dyadic fights (fight_id column). For each fight I have two lines (one per individual). What I want to do is fill the "opponent" column in each line, with the ID of the other individual within the same fight ID. So I want to generate the data in bold.

ID    FIGHT_ID    V3     OPP
12  --    1  --------       1    --    **13**
13  --    1  --------       0    --    **12**
14  --    2  --------       0    --    **15**
15  --   2  --------       1   --     **14**

I want to write the name of the opponent (fill the OPP column), which means copying the ID of the other individual involved in the same fight in the OPP column. I'm basically switching individuals to be each other's opponent. 
I thought to assign a column of either 1 or 0 within the same fight id, and then  making a loop within the fight id for all the dataset, to do something like 
: “if v3 = 1, copy the value of ID where v3 = 0, and if v3 = 0, copy the value of ID where v3 = 1”. 
The concept is quite easy but I can’t seem to figure it out (I could if they were on the same line, but here we have to look for a value in another line).
In R language, i would like to do this:

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
for (j in 1:length(levels(data$Fight_ID))) {
    data$OPP[i] <- if(data$v3[i]==1) **data$ID[i]** else if (data$v3[i]==0) **data$ID[i]**
}

Except that in the bold part, I want to write the value of data$ID[i] but where v3 == 0 , and vice versa for the second bold one.
If it would exist, it would be something like "data$ID[i] where data$v3[i]==0"  .

There are obviously other ways to do this, but this is the one that seems logical to me, with the R knowledge that I have. 
Thanks for the help!
Francesca

Comment: Francesca welcome to stackoverflow. Please format properly the code snippets in your question using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `plyr`, supposing you only have `2` lines per `id`:

```
df = data.frame(id=12:15, fight_id=c(1,1,2,2), v3=c(1,0,0,1))
#  id fight_id v3
#1 12        1  1
#2 13        1  0
#3 14        2  0
#4 15        2  1

library(plyr)
ldply(split(df, df$fight_id), function(u) transform(u, opp=rev(u$id)))

#  .id id fight_id v3 opp
#1   1 12        1  1  13
#2   1 13        1  0  12
#3   2 14        2  0  15
#4   2 15        2  1  14
```

Or base R:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$fight_id), function(u) transform(u, opp=rev(u$id))))

#    id fight_id v3 opp
#1.1 12        1  1  13
#1.2 13        1  0  12
#2.3 14        2  0  15
#2.4 15        2  1  14
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(split(df, df$fight_id), function(u) transform(u, opp=rev(u$id))))

#   id fight_id v3 opp
#1: 12        1  1  13
#2: 13        1  0  12
#3: 14        2  0  15
#4: 15        2  1  14
```

Still with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,opp:=rev(id), by=fight_id]

#> df
#   id fight_id v3 opp
#1: 12        1  1  13
#2: 13        1  0  12
#3: 14        2  0  15
#4: 15        2  1  14
```

And a very funny base R one without loop :)

```
df     = df[order(df$id),]
df$opp = df$id[rep(seq(0,length(df)/2,2), each=2)+2:1]

#> df
#  id fight_id v3 opp
#1 12        1  1  13
#2 13        1  0  12
#3 14        2  0  15
#4 15        2  1  14
```

Comment: Well, you covered everything except a dplyr one :-) `df %>% group_by(fight_id) %>% mutate(opp=rev(id))`

Comment: I know you have it :) I am not a big fan of dplyr reason why it's not a reflex!

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked! I used the first one, since it seemed the more compact.